# Does an iOS app accessing SF through Mobile SDK need to be listed as a "Connected App"

Tags: oauth2, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, connected-apps, login

It seems that my app is still functioning OK in production even though it is no longer listed under Manage Apps/Connected Apps. Should it be listed there? The problem I'm having is that my iOS app requires a re-login on every app launch with Sandbox, which makes testing cumbersome, but does not require this with production, and I can't find any config difference between the orgs that would cause this to happen.

Answer (score 4):

This is similar to the question I answered [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14893/can-i-use-the-just-released-sfdc-mobile-sdk-to-create-a-mobile-app-that-works-fo). The Connected app - client id and client secret can be from any org and it does not matter if you're not seeing that connected app in your org. [This](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14012/how-is-it-that-some-oauth-authenticated-apps-dont-require-an-org-to-create-a-co) thread may also help understand this better.

As for the other part of your question

> The problem I'm having is that my iOS app requires a re-login on every
>   app launch with Sandbox, which makes testing cumbersome, but does not
>   require this with production

That's unusual. You can definitely create another Connected app in your Sandbox to see if this resolves the issue.