# How to distribute an app independent of salesforce org

Tags: mobile, connected-apps, mobilesdk

When developing an app for Android or iOS, it seems mandatory to set up a connected app in your own org and use the key from it in the bootconfig.json file. This is all easily done when developing and testing on a single org, but what happens when I want to distribute the app on Google play/Appstore? Obviously the app should be usable by people on many different orgs, but without the connected app backing it, they will not be able to reach their data. How is this best handled?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a developer, you only need to create the connected app once, in a Developer Edition. You publish your app, and it's good to go. You do not need to create a connected app configuration in any other org. Users from other orgs can log in via your app, without there being a corresponding connected app in their own org.

Comment: Are you sure that what you said is always true? i think it is true when you are developing app for single organization but not otherwise. if you are developing app that can be used by any organization then you will need to create managed package and install that on every org. thoughts?

Comment: I'm certain it's always true. Go to http://workbench.developerforce.com, login via OAuth and see your data, APIs etc. Did you install the connected app in your org? Better yet, create a connected app in one developer edition org, then use it in another. See also http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/14021/67

Comment: I understood what you said but not sure why does SFDC documentation is saying like:  "The app is created in one organization and installed on other organizations. This is how an entity with multiple organizations or an ISV would use connected apps."  https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com

Comment: Actually, I could have used better language in my answer. Creating a connected app happens once, then you can install it in other orgs, but that isn't the same as creating more connected app keys and secrets.

Comment: Yes, i agree to that. As we use same share secrete and consumer key for all the installs of connected apps so in nut shell its not like creating new connected app when you install it.

Comment: And what if we need to update some params of this connected app created many years ago in dev org, but no one remember what dev org was used? Is there any chance to find this dev org by only having consumerKey and consumerSecret of connected app itself ?

Comment: @wesaw Oooh - that doesn't sound good. The only thing I can think is to both (1) open a ticket with Salesforce and (2) ping the Developer Evangelism team. Someone like Josh Birk or Peter Chittum might be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding it works like this:

1) You create connected app in you dev org

2) Then you create Android app providing details for your connected app in bootconfig.json file

3) After testing you package your connected app on SFDC and install it on your test org

4) then you install your Android app on test device

5) When you first try to access your Android app it ask SFDC user name pass when your provide details of your test org which has your connected app installed it binds your device successfully with your test org and not dev org.