# Is Connected Apps the way to integrate a 3rd Party application?

Tags: rest-api, integration, connected-apps

I want to integrate my application with Salesforce. Some of my users have Salesforce accounts, and I want them to be able to sync their data in Salesforce with my system. I decided to use the REST API to tackle the integration. There are 2 possible scenarios for me:

-Username/Password flow. It is not what I would want. I get access to all their data and realistically none of my users would agree to give access to all their data.

-User Agent flow. I am planning on creating a Connected App, pack it, and redistribute it with my clients.

I would like to stick with the User Agent flow. Just wanted to ask if this was the way to go, since I am relatively new to Salesforce Integrations.

Thank you for all your help in advance!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your app is either on a mobile device or the desktop, then, yes, user agent flow is your best option. If it's a web app, however, you should look at web server flow.

Comment: Thanks for the info. How would I distribute the settings I have in the Connected App I created with my Developer account? I am still not getting how this works... Again, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Great question! The answer is, you don't need to! See http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/36973/67

Comment: Thanks for answering my previous question. I have another one. As said in my question, I want to bridge my users' data to my application, that is the purpose of the Connected App. Ideally, from my web application (in PHP) I will redirect the user to log into salesforce with their credentials, get the token from the chosen flow, and I will be able to make requests to their Salesforce instance and obtain their data. Am I on the right track? How do you publish a Connected App. I read https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Digging_Deeper_into_OAuth_2.0_on_Force.com but it is still unclear. Thanks!

Comment: IIRC, you package it for distribution on the AppExchange: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=connected_app_edit.htm&language=en_US BTW - asking new questions in comments doesn't get them much exposure. Better to hit the 'Ask Question' link at the top of the page to actually ask a new question.

Comment: Apparently packaging an App is a legacy feature.  I found this article that says so. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/134357/package-connected-app Sorry, I will post a different question next time.